# Best WP cache plugin for large site

Tags: plugins, cache

I'm looking for WP cache plugin which is able to handle large number of pages. approx. 1 mil. I'm considering W3 total cache , WP super cache and few more , unfortunately I don't know which one is the best for large site. 
Can you suggest one ?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend W3 Total Cache. It optimizes over several different aspects of the site (HTML, database, etc.) and I haven't ran into any issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/web-tutorials/wordpress-caching-whats-the-best-caching-plugin/

they ran some Benchmarking for the top WordPress cache plugins and also of combination of different DB and widget cache plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a pretty extensive article about WP Super Cache, Autoptimizer, and using a CDN network called WPCDN (only $6/month!) [here](http://wpverse.com/2011/02/my-obsession-speeding-up-wordpress/).

I personally like WP Super Cache over W3 Total Cache because it's a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've been happy with [Quick Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-cache/) - straightforward to use, works on multisite and a bit lighter but not as configurable as W3 Total Cache.

W3 Total Cache's killer feature is being able to offload onto a CDN which is why sites like mashable.com and smashingmagazine.com etc use it.

Answer (score -1):

W3 Total Cache "The Best" in my opinion, however it is not fully functional for Multisite. Frederick from W3TC said it himself. The only way to use it is to activate it one by one,  quick cache seems to be the best option along with Super Cache.